# How can I cut the large space at the bottom of the subplot in plotly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I'm using plotly to generate interactive plots. In my case I'll have one table and a plot in one figure.
[image]

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import plotly.offline as offline
from plotly import tools
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1=go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 3, 5], name='abc', mode = 'lines+markers', xaxis='x1', yaxis='y1', showlegend=True)
trace2=go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3], name='cba', mode = 'lines+markers', xaxis='x1', yaxis='y1', showlegend=True)
trace3=go.Table(
        domain=dict(x=[0, 1], y=[0, 0.5]),
        header=dict(values=['', 'fields1', 'fields2', 'fields3']),
        cells=dict(values=[[['row1'], ['row2'], ['row3']], [['11'], ['12'], ['13']], [['21'], ['22'], ['23']], [['31'], ['32'], ['33']]], font = dict(color = '#506784', size = 11))
        )
axis=dict(
    showline=True,
    zeroline=False,
    showgrid=True,
    mirror=True,
    ticklen=4,
    gridcolor='#ffffff',
    tickfont=dict(size=10)
)

param1 = dict(
    xaxis1=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0, 1], anchor='y1', showticklabels=False)),
    yaxis1=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0.55, 1], anchor='x1', tickprefix='$', hoverformat='.2f')),
        )
layout1 = dict(
    title='Bitcoin mining stats for 180 days',
    margin = dict(t=100),
    showlegend=False,
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(228, 222, 249, 0.65)'
)
layout1.update(param1)
fig1=dict(data=[trace1, trace2, trace3], layout=layout1)
offline.plot(fig1, auto_open=False, output_type='file', filename='abc.html')
```

How can I remove the space below the table? Can the size of the fiture be changed automatically according to the actual size of the elements?

Comment: Isn't there something like `tight_layout` in plotly?

Comment: There's no such thing like tight_layout() I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your `domain` parameter, especially where you set yaxis:

```
domain=dict(x=[0, 1], y=[0, 0.5]),
```

and

```
yaxis1=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0.55, 1],
```

By code you say that the table will be drawn between 0% to 50% on the yaxis. And graph  - between 55% to 100%. But look! You table is too small to fill that gap(50%).

So you have to options to solve the problem:

1. Increase amount of data in your table. Then size of table increase and gap will decrease and will disappear afterwards;
2. Or turn table to bottom and increase graph size(for example 0-15% to table  and 15-100% for graph by yaxis) and result should be something like this (full code below):
   [image: 100% your graph]

Code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import plotly.offline as offline
from plotly import tools
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1=go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 3, 5], name='abc', mode = 'lines+markers', xaxis='x1', yaxis='y1', showlegend=True)
trace2=go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3], name='cba', mode = 'lines+markers', xaxis='x1', yaxis='y1', showlegend=True)
trace3=go.Table(
        #Set space for table from 0% to 15%
        domain=dict(x=[0, 1], y=[0, 0.15]),
        header=dict(values=['', 'fields1', 'fields2', 'fields3']),
        cells=dict(values=[[['row1'], ['row2'], ['row3']], [['11'], ['12'], ['13']], [['21'], ['22'], ['23']], [['31'], ['32'], ['33']]], font = dict(color = '#506784', size = 11))
        )
axis=dict(
    showline=True,
    zeroline=False,
    showgrid=True,
    mirror=True,
    ticklen=4,
    gridcolor='#ffffff',
    tickfont=dict(size=10)
)

param1 = dict(
    xaxis1=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0, 1], anchor='y1', showticklabels=False)),
    #Set space to graph from 15% to 100%
    yaxis1=dict(axis, **dict(domain=[0.15, 1], anchor='x1', tickprefix='$', hoverformat='.2f')),
        )
layout1 = dict(
    title='Bitcoin mining stats for 180 days',
    margin = dict(t=100),
    showlegend=False,
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(228, 222, 249, 0.65)',
    autosize=True,
)
layout1.update(param1)
fig1=dict(data=[trace1, trace2, trace3], layout=layout1)
offline.plot(fig1, auto_open=False, output_type='file', filename='abc.html')
```

Also you able to set xaxis parameters to get more nice plot (set space for plot from 25% to 75%):
[image]

Comment: Hi, @Oysily. Thanks for your help. The solution you provided can make this plot quite nice. But because I'll put many Scatters and Tables in one html page and the column count of each table may differ much. How can the exact ratio of the figure and table should be set then remains another problem

Comment: @张张彪, if I asked for your question, please dont forget to mark it as answer. Thanks!) If you found another problem, you can ask again